# The loop does not work for the second iteration

Tags: java

1. The loop does not run after the first time

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] argh) {
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                sum += (a + (Math.pow(2, i) * b));
                System.out.print(sum + " ");
            }

        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

> Input   2  0 2 10  5 3 5
>
> Your Output (stdout)  2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046
>
> Expected Output Download  2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046 8 14 26 50
>   98

Answer (score 1):

In your code, both inner and outer loops use the same variable. After the first inner loop execution finish value of i = 10. So in the second iteration of the outer loop, the loop condition fails. Since i = 10, t = 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        //sum should be here
        int sum = 0;

        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sum += (a + (Math.pow(2, j) * b));
            System.out.print(sum + " ");
        }

    }
    in.close();
}
```

And also variable sum should be declared inside the outer loop to reset count after the inner loop execution is completed once.

Answer (score 0):

use separate int variable in inner loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sum += (a + (Math.pow(2, i) * b));
            System.out.print(sum + " ");
        }

    }
```